# Updating single column in Oracle database

Tags: python, cx-oracle

How do I update a single column in Oracle database using Python? My script basically makes a list of strings like ["abc","world",...] and tries to update a particular column in oracle database.

```
var = ["abc","world",...]
cursor.prepare("INSERT INTO table(col10) VALUES (:var)")
cursor.executemany(None, var)
```

But I end up getting "DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number".

Answer (score 0):

See [this explanation](http://www.gingerandjohn.com/archives/2004/02/26/cx_oracle-executemany-example/) of using executemany.  You need a list of dicts, each one having a key 'var', with the values being the strings you have in your var list.

Comment: if you use key as index for iteration and strings as values with dict.setdefault() or collections.defaultdict you can negate dictionary cannot have same key problem